# trying to fetch some data from user url input, before reveal TextFormField and initial them with the fetched data

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, facebook-opengraph

so basically i'm new to dart and flutter.
the problem is when i asking from the user for url input and then i fetching OpenGraph data from the input link and trying to reveal a new Column with TextFormFields with initialValu of what i getting from the url's open graph

i tried to set TextFormField controller.text with the new data and also tried to set a var that i set when the user presses the submit button but i keep getting an errors about it

```
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Reloaded 5 of 635 libraries in 762ms.

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building EditPostScreen(dirty, state: _EditPostScreenState#f6ac9):
'package:flutter/src/material/text_form_field.dart': Failed assertion: line 117 pos 15: 'initialValue == null || controller == null': is not true.


Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md

User-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was
    MaterialApp 
lib\main.dart:25
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#2      new TextFormField 
package:flutter/…/material/text_form_field.dart:117
#3      _EditPostScreenState.build 
package:crusty/…/edit_post/edit_post_screen.dart:57
#4      StatefulElement.build 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4047
#5      ComponentElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3941
#6      Element.rebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3738
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Reloaded 5 of 635 libraries in 700ms.
```

that is my all widget

```
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _urlController = TextEditingController();
  final _titleController = TextEditingController();
  final _imageController = TextEditingController();


  var _isFetchedUrl = false;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _urlController.dispose();
    _imageController.dispose();
    _titleController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(''),
      ),
      body: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextFormField(
              controller: _urlController,
              autofocus: true,
              decoration:
                  InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter the url for your post'),
              validator: (value) {
                bool _validURL = Uri.parse(value).isAbsolute;
                if (value.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Please enter url for your new post';
                } else if (_validURL) {
                  return 'Pleas make sure you entered valid URL';
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
            _isFetchedUrl == false
                ? Container()
                : Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      TextFormField(
                          controller: _titleController,
                          initialValue: _titleController.text,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              hintText: 'Enter title for your post'),
                          validator: (value) {
                            if (value.isEmpty) {
                              return 'Please enter title for your new post';
                            }
                            return null;
                          }),
                      TextFormField(
                          controller: _imageController,
                          initialValue: _imageController.text,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              hintText: 'Enter subtitle for your post'),
                          validator: (value) {
                            if (value.isEmpty) {
                              return 'Please enter subtitle for your new post';
                            }
                            return null;
                          }),
                    ],
                  ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
              child: RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  // Validate returns true if the form is valid, or false
                  // otherwise.
                  if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                    // If the form is valid, display a Snackbar.
                    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                        SnackBar(content: Text('Processing Data')));
                  }
                  var data = await OpenGraphParser.getOpenGraphData(_urlController.text);
                  print(data['description']);

                  setState(() {
                    _titleController.text = data['description'];
                   _imageController.text = data['image'];
                   _isFetchedUrl = true;
                  });
                  // print(_urlController.text);
                },
                child: Text('Load my post'),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

i would like to make something like in Facebook when you past a link its immediately makes a preview of that link but i need the ability for the user to edit it after i load the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because you can't set an `initialValue` and a `controller` at the same time to a `TextFormField`, is one or the other.

If you want to set an initial value using a controller, then when you initialize the controller you could pass an initial value to it, like this:

```
final _urlController = TextEditingController(text: "Initial value");
```

Comment: can you explain how i initialize only after i getting the data from the url?

Comment: You could do _urlController.text = newText;

Comment: i got it, i over complicated it but finally got it, thenx!